# Catch XML with custom Classes

Tags: c#, web-services, class, variables, xml-serialization

I have so many clases, but I want to catch the sent and the recived information via XML ... The thing is that I don't want to create a Serializer every time i catch an XML doc, so I want to ask you if anyone know how to pack a class type into a TypeOf()

Im trying to create a function that Works something like this:

```
public void createXML(string fileName, string route)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializador = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(THIS IS WHAT I WANNA CHANGE TO A VARIABLE PARAMETER));
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@""+ route + fileName + ".xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    }
```

So what I want to do is to call this function and créate an XML whenever I want, but the thing is that inside the TypeOf() command, I can't figure out a way to put different classes there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) for this task.

```
public void createXML<T>(string fileName, string route)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializador = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@""+ route + fileName + ".xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    }
```

Comment: It worked, but now im running in a different problema, it seems the filestream wont accept the rout im placing in ... Any advice on this issue??... BTW thanks alot for the answer :)

Comment: No problem. Is the route definitely in the right format? `@""` looks odd to me, maybe that should be `"@"`, or removed completely? Also, if you are using backslashes in the route string, check that they are escaped correctly (use \\ in URLs, not \ ). 

It's also possible that you might need an extra forward slash `/` between `route` and `fileName`, but I don't know how these are set up. Maybe one of these things will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: If i use backslash instead of normalone it marks it as a syntax error, and also the way im suppossed to put the route is like this @"route/file.xml" ... So i tried putting in the route i just created and placed it before the file name with a + sentence like this @"" + route + "/" + filename + ".XML" ... With this im trying to get a XML file every time my WebService is consumed ... Trying to make it dynamic, i just keep running with issues, one after another ... The good thing is that guys like you keep helping me kindly and it is finally weekend haha ... Ill keep trying to solve it. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i got this so far and if i put the route manually it Works, if i put a custom route is brings an error message saying something about the provided route formant isnt admited, this is my code ... I get the directory, créate it if its not there, then i créate the name of the file, but when i try to créate the XML it just pops the error:

```
public string[] createDir(string flow, int enclosure, string transaction, string method)
    {
        DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Now;
        libs.Catalogos objCatalogos = new libs.Catalogos();
        string day, month, year, hora, min, seg, time, ruta, fileName, name;
        string[] datos = new string[2];
        int existe;
        name = objCatalogos.convertRecinto(enclosure);
        day = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
        //day = "13";
        month = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
        year = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
        hora = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
        min = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
        seg = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
        time = hora + "_" + min + "_" + seg;
        ruta = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WsDesarrollo2\" + @"XML" + @"\Empresa_" + name + @"\Flujo_" + flow + @"\Año_" + year + @"\Mes_" + month + @"\Dia_" + day + @"\";
        existe = verifyDir(ruta);
        if (existe == 0)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        }
        fileName = "" + ruta + transaction + "_" + method + "_" + time;
        datos[0] = ruta;
        datos[1] = fileName;
        return datos;
    }

    public void createXML<T>(string fileName, string route, T objeto)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializador = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"" + route + @"\" + fileName + ".xml");
        serializador.Serialize(tw, objeto);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i solved this issue and im just comming to post the final result, just in case anyone needs it, this is the final code where i créate a directory, or validate if it already exists and then créate an XML for any tipe of object that goes in or out of a webservice, so this is the library:

```
public class xmlLog
{
    public int verifyDir(string dir)
    {
        bool tryDir;
        tryDir = Directory.Exists(dir);
        if (tryDir == false)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public string[] createDir(string flow, int enclosure, string transaction, string method)
    {
        DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Now;
        libs.Catalogos objCatalogos = new libs.Catalogos();
        string day, month, year, hora, min, seg, time, ruta, fileName, name;
        string[] datos = new string[2];
        int existe;
        name = objCatalogos.convertRecinto(enclosure);
        day = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
        month = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
        year = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
        hora = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
        min = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
        seg = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
        time = hora + "_" + min + "_" + seg;
        ruta = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WsDesarrollo\" + @"XML" + @"\Empresa_" + name + @"\Flujo_" + flow + @"\Año_" + year + @"\Mes_" + month + @"\Dia_" + day + @"\";
        existe = verifyDir(ruta);
        if (existe == 0)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        }
        fileName = "" + ruta + transaction + "_" + method + "_" + time;
        datos[0] = ruta;
        datos[1] = fileName;
        return datos;
    }

    public void createXML<T>(string route, string fileName, T objeto)
    {
        string file = Path.Combine(route, fileName + ".xml");
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer slzr = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file);
        slzr.Serialize(tw, objeto);
    }
}
```

At the end of all this mess i managed to create a new directory and create an XML with just 2 code lines every time i need them, wich are the following ones:

```
string[]  = objXML.createDir("IN", Convert.ToInt32(recinto), M903In.transaccionAduana, "903");
objXML.createXML(paramXML[0], paramXML[1], M903In);
```

I know this wont work for everyone, but this is the way i managed to work with to creade dinamy routes and filenames for XML documents on a webservice.

Hopefully it helps someone :3